# when using the crewmate information button, it displays the information far beyond the screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any way to make some kind of border to prevent button from stretching forever or maybe a way to split the info into 2 different buttons in a more manageable size?

```html
#Crewmate Button info
def myClick1():
    myButton1 = Button(root, text=people_json, fg="white", bg="black")
    myButton1.grid(row=1, column=0)

myButton1 = Button(root, text="Crew Data", padx=70, pady=8, command=myClick1, fg="white", bg="black")
myButton1.grid(row=0, column=0,)

for p in people_json["people"]:
        print("Number of people in space: ", p["name"])
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the title of a Button to display information?  That's just bizarre - a Label, Text, or Message widget would be far more appropriate, and all are capable of breaking the text into multiple lines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.